# Many to Many com Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, fluent-api

Estou fazendo um mapeamento com [Fluent API](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx) e me veio uma duvida em como devo fazer o mapeamento muito para muito.

Por exemplo, tenho as classes abaixo.

```
public partial class Territories
{
    public Territories()
    {
        this.Employees = new HashSet<Employees>();
    }

    public int TerritoryID { get; set; }
    public string TerritoryDescription { get; set; }
    public int RegionID { get; set; }

    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employees> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

e

```
public partial class Employees
{
    public Employees()
    {
        this.Employees1 = new HashSet<Employees>();
        this.Orders = new HashSet<Orders>();
        this.Territories = new HashSet<Territories>();
    }

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TitleOfCourtesy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int? ReportsTo { get; set; }
    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employees> Employees1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Employees Employees2 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Territories> Territories { get; set; }
}
```

Na minha classe `EmployeesMap` criei o mapeamento.

```
HasMany(p => p.Territories)
.WithMany(p => p.Employees)
.Map(m =>
{
  m.ToTable("EmployeeTerritories");
  m.MapLeftKey("EmployeeID");
  m.MapRightKey("TerritoryID");
});
```

Minha duvida aqui é na minha classe `TerritoriesMap` devo fazer novamente o relacionamento ou não? ou seja, fazer.

```
HasMany(p => p.Employees)
.WithMany(p => p.Territories)
.Map(m =>
{
  m.ToTable("EmployeeTerritories");
  m.MapLeftKey("EmployeeID");
  m.MapRightKey("TerritoryID");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você que decide, não é necessário fazer isso pra funcionar. Mapear só de um lado já faz tudo funcionar como deveria.

Lembre-se que ter propriedades de navegação dos dois lados da relação causa uma dependência circular e você vai ter que lidar com isso em caso de serialização dos dados.

Answer (score 3):

Como podemos ver no exemplo [aqui](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), você precisa configurar somente de um lado.

Exemplo:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() 
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolDBContext : DBContext
{
    public SchoolDBContext() : base("SchoolDB-DataAnnotations")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasMany<Course>(s => s.Courses)
                .WithMany(c => c.Students)
                .Map(cs =>
                        {
                            cs.MapLeftKey("StudentRefId");
                            cs.MapRightKey("CourseRefId");
                            cs.ToTable("StudentCourse");
                        });

}
```

Seu banco:

[image: banco]

Comment: Eu vi esse exemplo só que aqui ele faz no OnModelCreating e eu estou criando uma classe de Map separada para cada classe de modelo.

Comment: Na verdade não tem diferença, você só está separando as responsabilidades. No final, você vai ter que chamar a sua classe dentro do OnModelCreating de qualquer jeito.

Comment: para você chamar suas classes no onModelCreating: modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmployeesMap());

Comment: Isso eu fiz, mas foi ai que bateu a duvida, quando separei as repesabilidade fiquei na duvida em qual classe eu deveria ter a configuração e se teria que ter nas duas.

Comment: Então, mas na verdade quando você faz na classe separada e coloca ela dentro do OnModelCreating, ela vai agir da mesma maneira que no exemplo que eu dei acima. Aí é só você fazer a configuração em 1 lado apenas. Isso vale também para 1x1 e 1xN

Comment: Entendi, obrigado.